# Data requirements to forecast using ARIMA

Tags: time-series

IF I had 52 observations taken at weeks would this be enough data to forecast the following year using regressor augmented ARIMA if I believed the seasonality were yearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "regressor augmented ARIMA" you refer to [ARIMAX or regression with ARIMA errors](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/), then yes, this should work. Of course, you could not use 52 weekly dummies, because then you would not have enough degrees of freedom, but one or two Fourier terms (sine/cosine waves) should work nicely as regressors.

Comment: If I had 65 weeks of data instead of 52, wouldn't fitting 52 weekly dummies be over fitting?

Comment: Yes, it would still be. If you have more observations than parameters, you would at least be able to *identify* your model, but it would still be horribly overfit and likely no good for forecasting. Use Fourier terms instead.